# How to detect app_type within nginx.conf.erb in Phusion Passenger?

Tags: passenger

Is there a (recommended) way to determine within `nginx.conf.erb` the `app_type` that Phusion Passenger (in standalone mode) has autodetected, per its [autodetection algorithm](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/ruby/app_autodetection/standalone/)? In Passenger 5.1.8, we'd been relying on `AppFinder.looks_like_app_directory?`, but it looks like that's been made private in [5.1.11](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/commit/54b0e74c8b255696785cd396dcd1682ab9feb30c).

We could simply look for any of `["config.ru", "passenger_wsgi.py", "app.js", ".meteor"]` ourselves but would prefer to rely on the `app_type` already detected, particularly if it was manually specified with `--app-type` at the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are in a server block, then `<%= nginx_option(app, :app_type) %>` should work for you.

If you just need it for conditional stuff, not output then `app[:app_type]` is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. Though it looks like `:app_type` is only populated (in 5.1.8 and 5.1.11, at least) with a value (in the context of `nginx.conf.erb`) when `--app-type` is specified at the command line and not when autodetection is used?

Comment: Yeah this only gets you the overrides, the autodetection is done in the c++ passenger core in all cases except passenger enterprise mass deployment. So you'll want to look for the startup files and then defer to `app[:app_type]` if set.